# Jest with create-react-app - unexpected token errors

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I am working on an application that was recently converted from an old Webpack build to use `create-react-app`. Most of the transition has went smoothly, but I'm running into some major issues with the previous unit tests. When I run `npm test` which has the standard package.json test script of `"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"`, it says all my snapshot tests have failed. This is fine and expected since there have been a lot of changes, and the tests need to be updated.

However, when I just run `jest` or `jest --updateSnapshot`, all of my tests immediately fail with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` errors, most of which are related to `import`. This leads me to believe that Jest isn't using Babel to transform the ES6 syntax correctly.

Previously, we used a .babelrc file with these settings:

```
{
"presets": ["env", "react", "stage-0", "flow"],
"plugins": ["transform-runtime", "add-module-exports", "transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

But since Babel is already included in `create-react-app` I removed this file as well as any references to Babel. My package.json also does not have any special scripts set up for Jest itself.

I have tried adding some of the previously used Babel packages back in, but after further reading it seems those won't work anyway unless I eject from `create-react-app` and that is not an option at this time.

What would cause `npm test` to run correctly but `jest` to fail miserably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out it was a Babel issue. Even though `create-react-app` comes pre-configured, we still had to add in custom configuration since our app wasn't initially built with `cra`. I installed some new dev dependencies:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-jest": "^22.4.1",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
```

And also updated the `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-react-app"]
}
```

And now both `jest` and `npm test` both work as they should.